# MySQL syntax error while creating new table

Tags: php, mysql, database, syntax

I have been trying for hours to solve this issue, I have searched for the answers here and still can't figure it out what wrong with my code. I'm trying to create a new database and a table with PHP and MySQL:

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

$connectDB = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$connectDB) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = 'CREATE DATABASE user_records
    CREATE TABLE records_list (
    id INT(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    userpass VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL)';

if (mysqli_query($connectDB, $query)) {
    echo '<div class="alertSuccess"><span>Query successful</span></div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="alertError"><span>Query failed: <i>' . mysqli_error($connectDB) . '</i></span></div>';
}
```

?>

And here's the error:

```
Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE records_list ( id INT(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREME' at line 2
```

I'm using VSCode and XAMPP, latest MySQL 8.

Update: I have edited my code as @Phil and @Mark Walker suggested:

```
$queryCrDB = "CREATE DATABASE user_records;";
    
$queryCrTb = "USE user_records;
CREATE TABLE records_list (
id INT(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
userpass VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);";

if (mysqli_query($connectDB, $queryCrDB)) {
    echo '<div class="alertSuccess"><span>Query successful</span></div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="alertError"><span>Query failed: <i>' . mysqli_error($connectDB) . '</i></span></div>';
}
if (mysqli_query($connectDB, $queryCrTb)) {
    echo '<div class="alertSuccess"><span>Query successful</span></div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="alertError"><span>Query failed: <i>' . mysqli_error($connectDB) . '</i></span></div>';
```

But it still gives me syntax error at CREATE TABLE line.

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon after `CREATE DATABASE user_records` though I'm not even sure if you can execute multiple statements in one `mysqli_query()` call

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php "Performs **a** query" see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php because you have 2 queries. Anything ending in a `;` is a query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the create database before the create table.
Query below should work, note the semi-colons closing individual commands and the "USE database" to switch into the newly created db.

```
CREATE DATABASE user_records;
USE user_records;
CREATE TABLE records_list (
    id INT(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    userpass VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: It still gives me syntax error, but now from USE user_records; line

Answer (score 0):

[Based on mysql 8 doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html), it should be:

```
id INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

not

```
id INT(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
```

`PRIMARY KEY` and `AUTO_INCREMENT` are reversed